# How can I make a Navigation Drawer go to the back of the Layout when Closed?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

In my layout xml file i have a webView and a Navigation Drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </WebView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/boReFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_to_bookmarks"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:translationY="-480px"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="#03A9F4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,ImageContrastCheck" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/baHoFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/go_back_home"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:translationY="-320px"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="#E91E63"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/shLiFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/go_to_the_shopping_list"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:translationY="-160px"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="#E91E63"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_view_list_24"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/moBuFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/show_buttons"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="#E91E63"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

        <!--this the navigation view which draws
            and shows the navigation drawer-->
        <!--include the menu created in the menu folder-->
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />


    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I run this, I can't click on the webview at all. But if i switch the order of the webview and the navigation drawer, then i can press on the webview but i cannot open the navigation drawer (or it can't be seen). I want to be able to click and open both. How can i achieve this functionality?

Comment: `DrawerLayout` is meant to be used differently than what you have there. Both the main content and the drawer go inside of it. The `<DrawerLayout>` tags should be the root in your layout, then the `<ConstraintLayout>` with the main content goes inside that first thing, then the `<NavigationView>` after that.

Comment: Then the navigation view is opened by default though and when i close it the app crashes:
```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT```

Comment: Nope, not if it's done correctly. The `<NavigationView>` should still be a direct child of the `<DrawerLayout>`.

Comment: How can I do it correctly, can you show it in an answer?

Comment: Oh Direct Child. I put the navigation view inside the contraint layout

Comment: Yeah, you got it. It basically stays right where it was in the original setup; right before the closing `</DrawerLayout>` tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246555/discussion-between-louiskoder-and-mike-m).

Comment: You can put that in an answer now.

Comment: Oh, it's cool. Nothin' huge. I'm good, if you've got it working. Feel free to finish up this question however you like. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A typical pattern to achieve the overall goals you want here is to use a Toolbar and a hamburger icon to trigger open/close of the NavDrawer.

Without that, using your current approach, you could:

1. setup a Guideline within the ConstraintLayout,
2. have the WebView start from that guideline and end at the parent,
3. set the WebView width to 0dp to allow the Constraints to control the width.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline

Comment: May I have an example please?